# How do I serve a Hugo theme exampleSite?

Tags: hugo, hugo-theme

I'm coming from using Jekyll as a [Static Site Generator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_site_generator). Content and themes are normally kept in the same directory/git repo.

I'm trying to set up a Hugo site, using the bare-bones theme [Hugo Xmin](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin). It contains the standard directory `exampleSite`.

How can I serve the `exampleSite` with the theme using Hugo (locally)? after I:

```
git clone git@github.com:yihui/hugo-xmin.git
cd hugo-xmin
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one-line command is:

```
hugo server --source exampleSite/ --themesDir ../..
```

Alternatively, go into the `exampleSite` and serve with passing the parent directory as an argument:

```
cd exampleSite
hugo server --themesDir ../..
```